# JTable in JScrollPane fixed size with resizeable JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a `JTable` inside of a `JScrollPane`. I want to get the columns to stay fixed when I resize it. The rows stay the same size, and there is a scrollbar to move up and down. I can't get the scrollbar to work the same way on the vertical though.

Here is a picture of my project, where the y axis of Duke is perfectly normal, and has a scrollbar to scroll to the bottom of the image, the horizontal part is clearly messed up, and should not have expanded that far.

Also, if the frame was made smaller horizontally, there should be a scrollbar just like the vertical.

[image: Picture of Duke]

So my question basically ends up like this; How do you fix the size of a `JTable` to not resize within the `JScrollPane`, and then if it's too large for it, display scroll bars.

Btw, Each cell has an image, making up the big image.

Comment: Interesting concept (each cell having it's own portion of the image), nice :D

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the table's auto resize mode to "off"

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

Take a look at [`JTable#setAutoResizeMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode%28int%29) for more details.

**Update**

I should mention, this will mean you will become responsible for determine the size of each column.

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Setting and Changing Column Widths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width)